# VSTS Trigger Build when external repo changes

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Let's say I have 2 separate repo's: RepoFrontEnd and RepoBackEnd. When RepoFrontEnd changes (and gets built) then another BackEndRepo needs to be rebuilt. How can I set up such a trigger?

Comment: Does RepoFrontEnd build update the code in RepoBackEnd repository? What's the detail workflow?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to achieve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283797/vsts-continuous-integration-asp-net-core-and-angular-4-project. So, now I have to figure out how to trigger a build of RepoBackEnd (Core-P in the mentioned question) when RepoFrontEnd is built. So, this is a chained 2 repo's build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually done with the **Trigger Build Task**, you can find it in the VSTS Marketplace.

What it does is it enables the chaining of builds. And this is exactly what I needed. So, with this task in place for RepoFrontEnd, when its build is completed, it triggers the RepoBackEnd build.

Comment: [`Trigger Build Task`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Web Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks) and use Code pushed event to trigger sending  information to a URL (such as a website you developed), after receive the information you can send [queue a build by REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build). Detail steps as:

1. Develop a website with the functions of receiving information and queuing a build for BackEndRepo after receiving information.
2. Create a web hook for the project contains RepoFrontEnd repo. In Service Hooks tab (https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apps/hub/ms.vss-servicehooks-web.manageServiceHooks-project) -> Create subscription -> Web Hooks -> Next -> select **Code pushed** for Tigger on this type of event -> select **RepoFrontEnd** for repository -> Next -> set the URL as the website receiving information URL -> Test ( check if it works good) -> Finish.
3. Enable CI build for RepoFrontEnd build definition.

Now any changes are pushed to RepoFrontEnd, builds for RepoFrontEnd and BackEndRepo will be triggered.

Comment: Can I change (add/delete/remove file) another repo from the one that's built somehow? That'd be the perfect solution for chained builds.

Comment: Yes, you can add power shell script in your build definition to changes files.

Comment: That's completely irrelevant to the question.