# Trigger VSTS/TFS build based on blob

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to trigger an VSTS/TFS build based on the condition if a blob in  a storage account is updated?

I tried to create a function app, but with little to no result, I cannot trigger a VSTS/TFS build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution (from my understanding) will be to use a [logic app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/):

- Create a logic app that is triggered whenever a blob is added/updated into a specific container.
- Queue a VSTS build

[image: Logic Apps - Blob trigger - Queue VSTS Build]

**NOTE**

your VSTS account should have "Third-party application access via OAuth" enabled. (Go to Administration > Control panel > Settings page)

Comment: Hi @Thomas thank you for the answer, trying to configure a logic app results in a unauthorised clientrequestId. http://prntscr.com/jfm902

Comment: Do you have enough permissions ? I mean the account youre using to connect to VSTS through Logic app, does it have enough permissions ?

Comment: It says: The name of the account. This can be found in the instance URL i.e. {account}.visualstudio.com. The account should have "Third-party application access via OAuth" enabled to prevent errors in the operation.

Comment: In the TFS agent pools the account is an administrator. Where can I double check the access via OAuth? because I already accepted it configuring the logic app

Comment: you can check in VSTS: Administration > Control panel > Settings page. There is a `Third-party application access via OAuth` stuff

Comment: It indeed was on 'deny', ran the logic app and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger), it is possible to:

> ...start a function when a new or updated blob is detected. The blob contents are provided as input to the function.

Then, the only thing the Azure function should do it to [queue a build in VSTS with the help of REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/queue). You might also want to check the [Getting Started page of VSTS REST API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/) - it contains the basic samples to quickly get up to speed.